# Unity shader graph very slow on Xbox X

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, shader-graph

(Unity version 2020.3.27f1)

Hello,
I have created a gerstner wave shader for my game, but after exporting the game to Xbox X and trying it out, it is incredibly slow, getting 5-10 fps. Disabling the waves and exporting to Xbox gets me back to 60 fps. As I am using URP, I am using the unity shader graph for my shader.

I have also tried disabling parts of my shader one by one, but the only thing that seems to bring the FPS back to 60 is slapping a regular material onto the sea.

Theoretically, the graphics card on my computer should be slower than the Xbox X GPU, so I don't understand where the performance drop is, as it runs fine both in editor and when exported for PC.

Has anyone else had issues with shader graph performance on consoles, or could you recommend alternative ideas?

Comment: Shader Graph is nothing more than a _means to create shaders_ **not** a mechanism by which visuals are executed at runtime.

Comment: Try downloading the famous Unity _[Boat Attack](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/BoatAttack)_ sample from GitHub, building and deploying to Xbox X.  It too is using the URP and contains some mighty impressive water effects.